# How to bring sidebar top of header while both as fixed position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

HTML Code:

```
<div id="screenLeft" class="screen"></div>
<div id="screenTop" class="screen"></div>



<div id="container">
    
    <div id="content">
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot1<br />
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot2<br />
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot3<br />
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot4<br />
                  

    </div>
    
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.screen {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
}
#screenTop {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#screenLeft {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
#screenTop { top: 0; }
#screenLeft { left: 0; }


#content {
    margin: 100px;
}
```

**I have two Questions**

- how can I bring black sidebar on top of header while both is fixed?
- How can I show content div in whole screen if sidebar & header display is none?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrBj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:
How can I show sidebar on top of header while both are positioned fixed?

simple answer, you can use `z-index = number` (z-index = 100 for example),
reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> The **z-index CSS property** sets the order of a positioned element and its descendants. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.

example code:

```
.screen {
    position: fixed;
    start: 0;
}
#screenTop {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index:10;
}
#screenLeft {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    top:100px; /*To Prevent Overlapping*/
    z-index:9;
}
#content{
    margin: 50px;
}
```

---

Second question:
How can I show content div in whole screen if sidebar & header display is none?

You will need to use a little javascript to perform this,
Add the following code before the end of your `<body>` tag,
then modify it for your needs.

```
<script>
    function ToggleContent()
    {
        let screenTopDisplay = document.getElementById("screenTop").style.display;
        let screenLeftDisplay = document.getElementById("screenLeft").style.display;
        
        let toggleMargin =
            (screenTopDisplay = "" || screenTopDisplay = "block") && (screenLeftDisplay = "" || screenLeftDisplay = "block");
        
        let container = document.getElementById("container");
        
        if(toggleMargin)
        {
            container.style.margin = "100px 0px 0px 100px";
        }
        else
        {
            container.style.margin = "0px";
        }
    
    }
</script>
```

*remember to call the function when you show/hide the .screen `ToggleContent()`

Comment: Hi thank you explanation, I am getting unknown property on start:0.

Comment: Thank you for reply, the sidebar placed on top on header as fixed position but the content body not coming under, it went behind.

Comment: (@nylaL)   okay, you can replace `start: 0` with `left: 0`

Comment: (@nylaL) can you clarify more, what is shown on your screen?

Comment: Hi please find the current output pic in question the table is behind the sidebar. more I am looking for to min/max the sidebar.

Comment: (@nylaL) Okay, after seeing the two links you added, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your first Question add these 2 properties `top:0px;`(to start form to 0 of screen) and `z-index:99;` (to stack over the topbar) to sidebar id `#screenLeft`

For your 2nd Question after removing sidebar and top bar add this css
`#content { margin-left: 0; margin-top: 0; }`
it will remove margin form content div.

```css
.screen {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
}
#screenTop {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#screenLeft {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    top:0;
    z-index:99;
}
#screenTop { top: 0; }
#screenLeft { left: 0; }


#content {
    margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="screenLeft" class="screen"></div>
<div id="screenTop" class="screen"></div>



<div id="container">
    
    <div id="content">
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot1<br />
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot2<br />
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot3<br />
        Test Possition of Text and whatnot4<br />
                  

    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Avais z-index is working perfect, but issue is When doing fixed sidebar the body content going behind of header/sidebar. can you please help with it?

Comment: Try giving margin top and left on body. so it give space to leftbar and top bar.